# php strtotime thursday not working

Tags: php, strtotime

I have php functions to get dates from this and next week. All is good except thursday - output from thursday is empty.

Here is my code:

```
$pondeli1 = date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime( 'monday this week' ) );
$utery1 = date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime( 'tuesday this week' ) );
$streda1 = date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime( 'wednesday this week' ) );
$ctrvtek1 = date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime( 'thursday this week' ) );
$patek1 = date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime( 'friday this week' ) );

$pondeli2 = date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime( 'monday next week' ) );
$utery2 = date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime( 'tuesday next week' ) );
$streda2 = date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime( 'wednesday next week' ) );
$ctrvtek2 = date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime( 'thursday next week' ) );
$patek2 = date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime( 'friday next week' ) );
```

And lines with "thursday next week" are not returning anything...

Where is problem please?

Comment: work fine for me.... 15.02.2016
16.02.2016
17.02.2016
18.02.2016
19.02.2016
22.02.2016
23.02.2016
24.02.2016
25.02.2016
26.02.2016

Comment: Working as expected for me as well on phpfiddle.org

Comment: I've deleted my original comment; `thursday next week` should work as [per the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php). Your code works in phpfiddle as @Aukhan says.

Comment: Thanks, it is OK now. It was by misspeling variable... My bad

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
$ctrvtek2 =strtotime("next Thursday",$ctrvtek1);
```

Comment: what about if tomorrow is thursday but i want next weeks thursday as appears to be the case for the author?

Comment: This call will return next Thursday after $ctrvtek1 (which is this week Thursday)